# E-mail notification on new "voluntary feedback" in TFS 2018

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I'm trying to get an email notification when my "on-premise TFS 2018" receives a new "voluntary feedback".

I already have a "work item notification" that generates an email when a work item status changes, but a "Feedback response" doesn't apply to this rule.

The current subscription is the one in the image

[image: Subscription]

How can I trigger an e-mail on the "new feedback received"?

Comment: The states of Feedback Response are `Active` and `Closed`. I suspect the item is created with `Active` and never reach the server with an empty value.

Comment: Yes! @jessehouwing it works. So I did a filter with value `Active` and operator "Changes to". But I had to add a clause checking that the title contains "Voluntary" because I don't know the "work item type" of a "Feedback Response", any idea?

Comment: The wit is `feedback response`, but being a hidden type I'm not sure it shows up in the drop downs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statuses of the *Feedback Response* work item are **Active** and **Closed**, you'll need to change your filter so detect the first state in order to receive your notification.

The feedback client pre-fills this value as far as I know and the value will therefore never be empty on the server if the tools are used the way they should.